# How to write to the same command prompt with vbs in windows?

Tags: vbscript, command-prompt

I have vbs script and that creates folder, make archive and copy to that folder, upload to ftp and so on. I want it to write status to cmd after each step of execution( after creating folder, zip...)

The following opens cmd.exe and writes there "creates folder". That's exactly what I want.

```
Dim objShell, strCmd

strCmd = "%comspec% /k echo creates folder"
Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
objShell.Run strCmd, 1, True
```

But, how I can write to the same cmd window that just opened? If I use this

```
   strCmd = "%comspec% /k echo starting zip"    
    objShell.Run strCmd, 1, True
```

it opens new cmd window, but I want to write "starting zip" to previously opened cmd.
How I achieve this?

Comment: WScript.echo "starting zip" ?

Comment: It's opens popup and I don't want any popup or GUI I want to write to the same black command prompt

Comment: As Daniel Cook says, make sure you use cscript

Comment: @AlexK, indeed if I use cscript it works. Thanks guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To print to the command prompt use [wscript.echo](http://ss64.com/vb/echo.html).

I want to point out that the behavior of .echo is effected by how the script is loaded. For instance, if I run it from command prompt, like this: `test.vbs`, then the echo lines show up as pop-ups due to running wscript by default. However, if instead I load the file like this: `cscript text.vbs` all output goes to console as expected.